# Run-time error 1004 - Range of object failed - VBA 2013

Tags: vba, excel

I'm getting a run time error 1004, Method 'Range' of object '_Worksheet' failed.

This code worked before on a draft of this project, but when imported into new project file, i get this.... none of the named ranges or worksheet names have changed from previous version. Please help!

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
'Set Variables to populate combobox
Dim rngProjects As Range
Dim ws1 As Worksheet

Set ws1 = Worksheets("Validation")

For Each rngProjects In ws1.Range("Projects")

Me.cboProject.AddItem rngProjects.Value
Me.cboAccount.AddItem rngProjects.Value

Next rngProjects

'Add static data for combobox
Me.cboTransactionType.AddItem "Income"
Me.cboTransactionType.AddItem "Expense"
```

Comment: Which line gives you the error?

Comment: It does not give me a line, does not even give the option to Debug.  http://prntscr.com/bmrx1z

Comment: Strange. Have you tried fully qualifying the workbook? So `WorkbookName.Worksheets("Validation")`. If the named range "Projects" exists as you say it does, that is the only thing I can see that may cause an issue.

Comment: I think Kyle is saying do this: `Set ws1 = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Validation")`

Comment: Caught me in the middle of my edit @bernie!

Comment: I've used your suggestion, yet I get the same. Here's the full code of the userform, Not sure if because I am using two ranges in two different places effects this? http://pastebin.com/iXxyRRjs

Comment: Are you sure they didn't change? Did you do a copy of the sheet? If so the ranges will be referred to the Draft, hence, they don't exist as such in this Workbook -only as reference- check in the name manager (Formulas->Name Manager)

Comment: @Sgdva Yes, I built the whole thing from scratch, Just the code has been copied over, but I've kept the same name ranges and layouts.

Comment: Off Topic : - I made a common newb mistake on the old draft version, I set a login form, and made a typo on sheet to check and now I'm locked out forever. :D

Comment: Don't worry typos are a common thing, you may delete the question if so

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to me that either the sheet name changed (sometimes a leading or trailing space is not recognizable) or the name for the named range changed. Furthermore, it could also be that the named range moved to another sheet (other than the validation sheet).

If you check all of the above and furthermore use explicit references as suggested in the comments then you should be able to find the problem. Here is your code with some additional checks. Give it a try and let us know if this works or made you aware of the problem.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
'Set Variables to populate combobox
Dim rngProjects As Range
Dim ws1 As Worksheet
Dim bolFound As Boolean
Dim nm As Name

For Each ws1 In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    If ws1.Name = "Validation" Then bolFound = True
Next ws1
If bolFound = False Then
    MsgBox "Required sheet not found."
    Exit Sub
End If

Set ws1 = Worksheets("Validation")

For Each rngProjects In ws1.Range(ws1.Cells(8, 1), ws1.Cells(ws1.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp))
    frmAddTransaction.cboProject.AddItem rngProjects.Value
    frmAddTransaction.cboAccount.AddItem rngProjects.Value
Next rngProjects

'Add static data for combobox
frmAddTransaction.cboTransactionType.AddItem "Income"
frmAddTransaction.cboTransactionType.AddItem "Expense"

End Sub
```

As commented below, the indirect named range has been removed. Instead, the sheet is now directly referenced in the code. Like this any change of the named range will have no impact on the code. Instead, the offset of 8 rows is written in the VBA where it is *slightly* more secure.

Comment: Odd, while running I get an error message, http://prntscr.com/bmsaz4 I have also checked named ranges  http://prnt.sc/bmsahb Sorry if I'm just missing something, my mind is boggled.

Comment: Apparently, the carriage return caused a mild hick-up. So I removed it (as it was purely visual anyway). Have a look at the adjusted code and see if you can run it now.

Comment: Using Debug, I step through code to the Set ws1 - Worksheets("Validation") all okay, Then we go into the Named Range Check... I step through the block once, with no errors, on the second run, I the same error appears on :  If nm.RefersToRange.Worksheet.Name <> "Validation" Then

Comment: http://www.filedropper.com/investmenttracker-wip : link to the file. Username is RiglerKrave, Pass is 0506 Or you can use Username Jon, Pass - 9999

Comment: These are indirect named ranges. The named ranges **must** have changed from the original workbook (when the code still worked). Have a look at the first named range called `CurrentUser`: http://prnt.sc/bmsahb This is a true named range which can be used. The same is the case with `Table2` because both directly refer to a range on a sheet. The other ranges need to get evaluated first before they can be used / referenced (because of the `OffSet`). So, if you are asking here for the `rngProjects.Value` you are getting back: `=OFFSET(Validation!$A$8,,,COUNTA(Validation!$A$8:$A$1000))`.

Comment: Yet, in your code you are using `rngProjects.Value` to get back the project numbers. Suggestion: I'd remove **any** use of named ranges in the VBA code and directly reference the sheets. By using named ranges in your VBA code it is prone to break whenever someone fiddles with the ranges. The above code has been changed accordingly.

Comment: Would you suggest something like this?                                Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    With Worksheets("Sheet1")
        ComboBox1.List = .Range("A1:A" & .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).Value
    End With
End Sub

Comment: Yes, absolutely. But stick to the explicit coding and name the form up front. So, use `UserForm1.ComboBox1.List = .Range("A1:A" & .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).Value2`. Using `.Value2` instead of `.Value` gives you a little bit of a speed boost.

Comment: Thank you so much! You're code works brilliantly, I didn't realise it would be so simple. 

Is using Me.ComboBox1.list...... not the same?

Comment: Try to avoid in your code things such as `Me`, `ActiveWorkbook`, `ActiveSheet`, `Selection`, etc. These are *relative* references as they change. So, if you code runs a bit too long and I click on another sheet or actually look at another Excel file (which this one is still running) or even at another application (click on my browser) then `ActiveWorkbook` and `ActiveSheet` change and will cause your code to fail. The above terms should not be used. Instead, use absolute references which cannot change. Tell VBA exactly which sheet / form / file you want.

Comment: Thank you! That's cleared it up a lot. If I could buy you a beer I would!

Comment: Also, (as an additional remark to the last comment) absolute references render your code easier to read. If you are referring to `Selection` then I have to look in the previous lines of code which cell was last selected. Worse even, if the selection occurred in another sub in another module somewhere else in the file. Now imagine having lots of those. It's like revealing an archaeological site with a paintbrush. Not much fun.

Comment: Thanks for the beer. I will let you know if I ever get close to you. Yet, now that the UK is leaving the rest of the EU that's not very likely to happen anytime soon. ;)